# Can we unban GnomeSlice from chat.SE?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, chat

It has been many months since GnomeSlice was able to post in chat. This post isn't to discuss the why or the how that lead up to him getting banned, it is a request for the other half of his ban to be lifted early.

Enough is enough now, he has been banned for literally months, while still turning up frequently yet being unable to participate. He is a loyal and frequent user to stackexchange.

**Liberate GnomeSlice! Unban him from chat.SE!**

Comment: No, the duration of his site ban was not shortened. He was unbanned and then re-banned for a different reason.

Comment: My site ban was shorter to begin with, the length wasn't changed.  Thanks for trying I guess, but I suspect it's not going to be lifted early.

Comment: To my understanding, the site ban was not originally supposed to happen.  Before it could be fixed, he circumvented it via a sockpuppet which led to him keeping half the ban.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is six months an inordinately long time? Yes, yes it is, it is half a year in fact. This is intentional. That was the entire point of making it six months.

We had an arrangement, the terms were understood, and we're following through. We're not going to release a 6-month suspension early because "It's been 4 months". In fact, that's all the reason not to do it. 4 months is not 6 months. It ain't over yet, plain and simple. If we were going to only run for 4 months of suspension time, then we would've set the suspension time to 4 months. But we didn't. We set it to 6 months, so there's still two more months before the chat ban is lifted.

Comment: I've got a math book right here that *clearly* states that 4 is in fact greater than 6 and--oh wait, it's just upside down.

Comment: Maybe people will stop asking you to unban me in the chat now.  Those pings just make me sad.

Comment: I'll just say "chat sure would be better if @gnomeslice were here" instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here, have this handy dandy countdown from http://whendoesgnomeslicecomeback.weebly.com/

[image]

Comment: I still can't get over how downvoted this question is

Comment: I still can't get over how *upvoted* this question is.

Comment: yes I was surprised! (re: original comment)